# Configure JsonProcessingExceptionMapper to log in Dropwizard

Tags: json, jackson, jersey, dropwizard

I am working on a dropwizard application. I need to configure it to log the exception from `JsonProcessingExceptionMapper`.

Some of my config.yml file:

```
server:

type: simple

connector:
  type: http
  port: 0

requestLog:
  appenders: []

registerDefaultExceptionMappers: true
```

Been looking at `JsonProcessingExceptionMapper` and it's `showDetail` property but cannot figure it out. I am using dropwizard version 1.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. I was missing the property `detailedJsonProcessingExceptionMapper`:

```
server
  registerDefaultExceptionMappers: true
  detailedJsonProcessingExceptionMapper: true
```

Could not find this in the documentation. Could anyone point me to the right place?